# Installing Cockpit on 18.04 kernel 4.20

Tags: server, software-installation

I got a few Ubuntu 18.04.1 servers, and today I installed Cockpit on one of them, so I thought to add all of my servers to it.
One of my servers has kernel 4.20 due to an network card.
All the others has 4.15.

On the 4.15 servers I can install Cockpit by: `sudo apt install -y cockpit`
But not on the 4.20, it doesnt find the package at all.

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the /etc/apt/sources.list contained a minimum, so I took all sources entries from an 4.15 machine and now it works!